# Wants to achieve short cut with parameters not in End for efficient usage of shortcuts

Tags: sql-server, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

I am facing issue with following section :

> Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard --> Query Shortcuts

I am able to create shortcut for :

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM
```

Where i can keep table name in ssms and directly execute the query with shortcut assigned to the above query.

I want to achieve

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (TableName) WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Now for this the TableName is parameter and, i don't find any way to use like this.

Comment: You are asking for [query templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/templates-ssms?view=sql-server-2017), not shortcuts. [I Thought Everyone Did It Like That – SSMS Templates](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/i-thought-everyone-did-it-like-that-ssms-templates/) explains how to use replacement variables and set values with `Ctrl+Shift+M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcuts that you are editing are simple stored procedure call and this feature is not powerful enough to do what you want. From your description it would be a feature more like the one available in context menu when you right click a table and go `Script table as` -> `Selext to`. And to do that you need to find/write a plugin and that is a big topic.